# Date-time column names in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

I have a usage data per customer, collected per months during several years, shaped as ~(6000, 60).

Sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['user_1', 'user_2'], 'access_type': ['mobile', 'desktop'], '2018-09-01 00:00:00': [7,5], '2018-10-01 00:00:00':[1,3], '2018-11-01 00:00:00':[0,10]})

    id  access_type 2018-09-01 00:00:00 2018-10-01 00:00:00 2018-11-01 00:00:00
0   user_1  mobile  7   1   0
1   user_2  desktop 5   3   10
```

How do I change 40 selected date-columns to a datetime index (?) format, or other format that will allow selecting/slicing required periods of time as date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df2 = (df.melt(['id','access_type'], var_name='date')
        .assign(date = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['date']))
        .set_index('date'))

print (df2)
                id access_type  value
date                                 
2018-09-01  user_1      mobile      7
2018-09-01  user_2     desktop      5
2018-10-01  user_1      mobile      1
2018-10-01  user_2     desktop      3
2018-11-01  user_1      mobile      0
2018-11-01  user_2     desktop     10
```

If need `MultiIndex` use `set_index` with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
s = (df.set_index(['id','access_type'])
       .stack()
       .rename(index = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x), level=2))
print (s)
```

Or:

```
s = (df.melt(['id','access_type'], var_name='date')
        .assign(date = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['date']))
        .set_index(['id','access_type','date'])['value'])

print (s)
```

Comment: Also, to enable slicing with datetime, apply `pd.to_datetime()`

Comment: Thanks, @jezrael, but second step - `set_index(...).stack()` breaks down due to `ParserError: Unknown string format: value`. Before that my output is the same as in your df2.

Comment: @ande - hmmm, are in list of columns `['id','access_type']` only 2 values? And then is used `level=2` in `.rename(index = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x), level=2)` ?

Comment: @jezrael, no, as in `df2` in your code, there are three columns: `['id', 'access_type', 'value']`. Value has int type. Changing level to 3 produces other kind of error: `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @ande - so need ouput `s` from first code? Answer was edited.

Comment: @jezrael, thanks! updated request `(melt(...).assign(...).set_index(...)` works, although it is in plain text, not in dataframe formatting. Can't figure how to fix that...

Comment: @ande - output from `print (df2)` is txt? `print (type(df2))` is `string` ?

Comment: no, output of s is in text

Comment: @ande - Never seen before, how possible? what is `print (type(s))` ?

Comment: its `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`